# Ajax request with jQuery not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I haven't developed a long time, I lost a few reflexes.

Can someone help me?

According to Google Chrome, it happens nothing when I press submit :

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label for="title">Title :</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" />
    <label for="comment">Comment :</label>
        <input type="text" id="comment" />
    <label for="project">Project :</label>
        <input type="text" id="project" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        return false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://support.foo.com/insert_bug.aspx',
            data: 'username=mr%20dog&password=dog%3Ddog&short_desc=' + $('#title').val() + '&comment=' + $('#comment').val() + '&projectid=' + $('#project').val(),
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**insert_bug.aspx**

```
string username = Request["username"];
string password = Request["password"];
string short_desc = Request["short_desc"];
string comment = Request["comment"];
string projectid_string = Request["projectid"];
```

If I send the url from my browser, the bug is added.

Comment: Your function returns before the call to `ajax`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning from the `submit` event handler before your call to `.ajax`, which means your AJAX call is never even reached. You could move the `return` statement to the end of the function body:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //AJAX call...
    return false;
});
```

Or you could use the `preventDefault` method of the event object to the same effect:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //AJAX call...
});
```

Comment: My bad `:x` Your answer works of course, thanks. But the alert(msg) doesn't work, and Chrome tracker shows no response, any idea? When I send the url with my browser, I get a string "bugid: xx".

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://support.foo.com/insert_bug.aspx. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Google "same origin policy". The page which makes the request has to be on the same domain as the page the request is sent to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised if anything happens anywhere - you are returning false from teh submit function, before calling the `$.ajax` function.
Try:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://support.foo.com/insert_bug.aspx',
            data: 'username=mr%20dog&password=dog%3Ddog&short_desc=' + $('#title').val() + '&comment=' + $('#comment').val() + '&projectid=' + $('#project').val(),
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```